# Spring social SignIn with Facebook not working

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I work on an application and i want to add ProviderSignIn features. I place a button on my web page so people could connect ( signin) to my application using facebook. As documentation says (http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/signin.html), the oAuth dance  :
1. POST is made to signin/facebook work(seen in firebug)
2. GET is made to signin/facebook?code="somecode" work(seen in firebug)
3. GET is made to signin but this just displays my view signin.

The documentation says :

*If any error occurs while fetching the access token or while fetching the user's profile data, ProviderSignInController will redirect to the application's sign in URL. The request to the sign in URL will have an "error" query parameter set to "provider" to indicate an error occurred while communicating with the provider. The default sign in URL is "/signin" (relative to the application root), but can be customized by setting the signInUrl property.*

At step 3, my url is signin#*=* and not signin with error query parameter.

I don't understand why i am not getting error in query parameter ?

Comment: What did you set for your URLs in Facebook for the configuration for your Facebook app?

Comment: Hi, did you solve? same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own controller which extends ConnectController and implements it's methods. It worked for me.